# Bufferunderflowexception Java

Tags: java, exception, paintcomponent, filechannel, bufferunderflowexception

I am writing values to a file.

The values are written correct. In another application I can read the file without any exceptions.

But in my new application, I get a `Bufferunderflowexception` when trying to read the file.

The `bufferunderflowexception` refers to :

```
Double X1 = mappedByteBufferOut.getDouble(); //8 byte (double)
```

This is my code to read the file:

```
 @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
    MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBufferOut = null;
    FileChannel fileChannel = null;

    try {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        File file = new File("/home/user/Desktop/File");

        randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

        fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();

        mappedByteBufferOut = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, randomAccessFile.length());

        while (mappedByteBufferOut.hasRemaining()) {
          
            Double X1 = mappedByteBufferOut.getDouble(); //8 byte (double)
            Double Y1 = mappedByteBufferOut.getDouble();
            Double X2 = mappedByteBufferOut.getDouble();
            Double Y2 = mappedByteBufferOut.getDouble();
            int colorRGB = mappedByteBufferOut.getInt(); //4 byte (int)
            Color c = new Color(colorRGB);

            Edge edge = new Edge(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, c);

            listEdges.add(edge);

        }
        repaint();

        for (Edge ed : listEdges) {
            g.setColor(ed.color);
            ed = KochFrame.edgeAfterZoomAndDrag(ed);
            g.drawLine((int) ed.X1, (int) ed.Y1, (int) ed.X2, (int) ed.Y2);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            mappedByteBufferOut.force();
            fileChannel.close();
            randomAccessFile.close();
            listEdges.clear();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (randomAccessFile.length()>8){
              while (mappedByteBufferOut.hasRemaining()) {



              }
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getDouble%28%29) of java.nio.ByteBuffer:

> Throws:
> BufferUnderflowException - If there are fewer than eight bytes remaining in this buffer

I think that makes it pretty clear where this is Exception is coming from. In order to fix it, you need to make sure that the ByteBuffer has enough data in it in order to read a double (8 bytes) by checking `remaining()` instead of `hasRemaining()` which only checks for one byte:

```
while (mappedByteBufferOut.remaining() >= 36) {//36 = 4 * 8(double) + 1 * 4(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `Double` when you can use `double`

I suspect your problem is that you have bytes remaining at the start of the loop, but you didn't check how many bytes and there isn't enough.

I would also make sure you have the right byte endianness the default is big endian.

Comment: Changed Double to double, thanks for that.
What should I do to continue the loop when there are enough bytes?

Comment: You are about to read 36 bytes, you can check that `remaining() >= 36`